# Cypress Upload file error using selectfile - filename undefined

Tags: file-upload, cypress, automation-testing

Attempting to upload a file via a hidden 'input[type="file"]' element.

My code is : Get, Show and Select as per the cypress documentation
`cy.get('[data-cy="file-input"]').selectFile('cypress/fixtures/myfixture.json')`

```
cy.get('input[type="file"]')
     .invoke('show')                    
     .selectFile('cypress/fixtures/TestPNG.png')`
```

I'm getting the following. My file is there and I have tried with the full path name from my `C:.` Same result

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about the path to it?

Comment: Are you uploading the same file multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced but you can try to add `force` ?

```
cy.get('[type="file"]').selectFile(
  "cypress/fixtures/TestPNG.png",
  { force: true }
);
```

Comment: Will do, back in a mo. Thanks btw

Comment: No joy on that. Same error

Comment: Arf, and the error is is not more explicit ?

Comment: No, the same error

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer that worked for me on a hidden input element

```
  cy.fixture('TestPNG.png').as('myPNG')
                cy.get('input[type=file]')
                    .invoke('show')
                    .selectFile('@myPNG')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).